# tomcat connection interrupted after a period of inactivity

Tags: spring, tomcat, oracle11g, connection-pooling, hibernate-entitymanager

I am developing an application with `spring` and `hibernate entityManager`

The `oracle` database is outside the DMZ.

the connection will be interrupted after a period of inactivity by the `firewall`.

I added the `ValidationQuery` `select 1 from dual` in `context.xml` but it does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your datasource try to add the below. testWhileIdle

```
<Resource auth="Container"
      type="javax.sql.DataSource"
      name="jdbc/testt"
      driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
      url="jdbc:mysql://********/mydb"
      maxActive="10"
      maxIdle="5"
      validationQuery="SELECT 1"
      testOnBorrow="true"
      testWhileIdle="true"
      timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="10000"
      minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="60000"
      username="..." password="..."/>
```

Comment: I use Oracle DB , not MySql

Comment: The important information in this answer is not the mysql connection but the attributes startign with validationQuery, which you already have in Oracle-Lingo. Experiment with the other options and look up what they're doing: testOnBorrow, testWhileIdle, timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis, minEvictableIdleTimeMillis. Check if the connection pool has more options.